# Ошибка multiple values for argument

Tags: python, type-error

```
    def __init__(name):
        name = name
        deadline = True

    def work_hard(self, deadline=True):
        if self.deadline:
            print(self.name, 'Что ж, ещё часок поработаю!')
        else:
            print(self.name, 'Можно отдыхать')

tester_1 = Tester(name='tester_1')
tester_1.work_hard(deadline=False)  # 'tester_1 Можно отдыхать'
tester_2 = Tester(name='tester_2')
tester_2.work_hard(deadline=True)
```

получаю в результате ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/olga/PycharmProjects/Python_tasks/main.py", line 62, in <module>
    tester_1 = Tester(name='tester_1')
TypeError: Tester.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```

в чем может быть причина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что у вас не хватает части кода. В `work_hard` у вас есть параметр `self`, значит это метод класса, а в `__init__` у вас этого `self` и не хватает. И самого класса не хватает, хотя в коде вы создаете экземпляры этого класса: `tester_1 = Tester()` и `tester_2 = Tester()`

Вот так должен выглядеть ваш код:

```
class Tester:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.deadline = True

    def work_hard(self, deadline=True):
        if self.deadline:
            print(self.name, 'Что ж, ещё часок поработаю!')
        else:
            print(self.name, 'Можно отдыхать')


tester_1 = Tester(name='tester_1')
tester_1.work_hard(deadline=False)  # 'tester_1 Можно отдыхать'
tester_2 = Tester(name='tester_2')
tester_2.work_hard(deadline=True)
```